# Oozie generate set of files in directory

Tags: hadoop, workflow, oozie, oozie-coordinator

I'm trying to ingest log files into hadoop.

I'd like to use oozie to trigger my ingestion task (written in spark),and have oozie pass the filenames to my task.

I expect the log files to be set out as:

```
/example/${YEAR}-${MONTH}-${DAY}-${HOUR}:${MINUTE}/Log1/Log1.log
/example/${YEAR}-${MONTH}-${DAY}-${HOUR}:${MINUTE}/Log1/Log1.1.log
/example/${YEAR}-${MONTH}-${DAY}-${HOUR}:${MINUTE}/Log1/Log1.2.log
/example/${YEAR}-${MONTH}-${DAY}-${HOUR}:${MINUTE}/Log2/Log2.log
/example/${YEAR}-${MONTH}-${DAY}-${HOUR}:${MINUTE}/Log2/Log2.1.log
/example/${YEAR}-${MONTH}-${DAY}-${HOUR}:${MINUTE}/Log2/Log2.2.log
```

(etc).

So, now I have two problems:
1. How to get oozie to generate all the file names under /example/${YEAR}-${MONTH}-${DAY}-${HOUR}:${MINUTE}/Log1/ and pass it to my app; and

2. How to get oozie to in parallel generate all the file names under /example/${YEAR}-${MONTH}-${DAY}-${HOUR}:${MINUTE}/Log2/ and pass it to a second invocation of my task.

Answer (score 0):

DateTime wise File name create can be done by using small Java Program, which can be call from Oozie Workflow.xml, 
somthing like

```
String processedDateString = (new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddhhmmss")).format(new Date(timeInMilis));
```

and while calling the same jar in workflow

```
      <main-class>NameFile.jar</main-class>
      <arg>Path=${output_path}</arg>
      <arg>Name=${name}</arg>
      <arg>processedDate=${(wf:actionData('Rename')['ProcessedDate'])}</arg>
```

For Copying/Moving you can use same Java program with Copy Action.

for log1 and log2 location you can mention in job.properties